# How to count consective 1 in column and get max count of each group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with columns 'A' and 'flag'. i want to apply groupby function and get maximum count of consecutive 1 in each group

## input data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],'flag':[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1]})
```

## required output

```
output= pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],'consective_count_max':[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series` for consecutive values per groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), filter only `1` values by mask `m` and then count values by [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with `max` used for mapping by original column `A` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
m = df['flag'].eq(1)
s = df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum()[m]
df.A.map(s.groupby(df.A).value_counts().max(level=0))
print (df)
    A  flag  consecutive_count_max
0   1     1                      3
1   1     1                      3
2   1     0                      3
3   1     1                      3
4   1     1                      3
5   1     1                      3
6   2     0                      3
7   2     1                      3
8   2     1                      3
9   2     0                      3
10  2     1                      3
11  2     1                      3
12  2     1                      3
```

Comment: I think solution with `Series.max` and `level=0` is my solution, also `value_counts` isn't neccesary if OP works with flag 0 or 1

Comment: @ansev - hmmm, I like always general solutions, so I add `eq(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) with `level=0`. 
We can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to create a series with the original index:

```
blocks=df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum()
df['consecutive_count_max'] = (df['A'].map(df.groupby(['A',blocks])['flag']
                                             .sum()
                                             .max(level=0)))
print(df)

    A  flag  consecutive_count_max
0   1     1                      3
1   1     1                      3
2   1     0                      3
3   1     1                      3
4   1     1                      3
5   1     1                      3
6   2     0                      3
7   2     1                      3
8   2     1                      3
9   2     0                      3
10  2     1                      3
11  2     1                      3
12  2     1                      3
```

---

note that when adding, groups with `flag == 0` will never get a sum greater than the group with `flag == 1` therefore `df['flag'].eq(1)`  **is NOT required**.

If `flag` is not 1 or 0 and then it is necessary to check for example`df['flag'].eq('yes')` .we could use:

```
mapper = pd.crosstab(df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift())
                               .cumsum()
                              .loc[df['flag'].eq(1)], df['A']).max()
df['consecituve_count_max'] = df['A'].map(mapper)
#print(df)
```

**Detail**

```
print(df['flag'].ne(df['flag'].shift()).cumsum())

0     1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     6
10    7
11    7
12    7
Name: flag, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    col1=dd.flag.ne(1).cumsum()
    return dd.groupby(col1).flag.transform(sum).max()

df.groupby('A').apply(function1).rename("consective_count_max").pipe(df.join,on='A')
```

out：

```
 A  flag  consecutive_count_max
0   1     1                      3
1   1     1                      3
2   1     0                      3
3   1     1                      3
4   1     1                      3
5   1     1                      3
6   2     0                      3
7   2     1                      3
8   2     1                      3
9   2     0                      3
10  2     1                      3
11  2     1                      3
12  2     1                      3
```